# Producing a list of lists

Tags: scheme

I am trying to produce a list of lists which has *.
Here is what I have so far:

```
(define (position loc count)
  (cond [(empty? loc)empty]
    [else (cons (list (first loc) count)
                (position (rest loc) (add1 count)))]
    ))
```

So:

```
(position (string->list "**.*.***..") 0)
```

would produce:

```
(list
 (list #\* 0) (list #\* 1) (list #\. 2) (list #\* 3) (list #\. 4) (list #\* 5)     
 (list #\* 6) (list #\* 7) (list #\. 8) (list #\. 9))
```

Basically I am trying to get

```
(list (list (list #\* 0) (list #\* 1))
      (list (list #\* 3))
      (list (list #\* 5)(list #\* 6) (list #\* 7)))
```

I thought about using foldr but not sure if that will work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by _which has *_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not exactly a foldr solution though, you need a function that modifies it's behaviour based on prior input in order to group the continuous star characters. Check out my use of a boolean to switch behaviour upon finding a match.

```
(define (combine-continuous char L)
  (let loop ((L L) (acc '()) (continuing? #t))
    (cond ((null? L) (list (reverse acc)))
          ((equal? (caar L) char)
           (if continuing?
               (loop (cdr L) (cons (car L) acc) #t)
               (cons (reverse acc) 
                     (loop (cdr L) (list (car L)) #t))))
          (else (loop (cdr L) acc #f)))))

(combine-continuous #\* (position (string->list "**.*.***..") 0))
=->
;Value 19: (((#\* 0) (#\* 1)) ((#\* 3)) ((#\* 5) (#\* 6) (#\* 7)))
```

Comment: how can I modify this so it works in the intermediate student with lambda language?

Comment: I'm not familiar with that dialect, but you can convert the let loop into an internal definition and call is with the initial values after.  If you are more specific into what isn't working I can help further.